# How to have systemctl track the spawned process of a script?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, gameserver

As a followup to [one of my previous posts](https://serverfault.com/questions/1044197/how-to-install-gmod-server-as-system-service-on-ubuntu), I'm using systemd to run a GMod server on Ubuntu 18.04. My systemd script looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gmod Server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=rooday # the user I normally run run_gmod.sh with
ExecStart=/datadrive/srcds/run_gmod.sh
Restart=Always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and it runs my server fine, but the issue is that `systemctl status` and `journalctl` aren't showing the actual logs of the server binary.

This is because `run_gmod.sh` runs the `srcds_run` script (part of the [srcds](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Dedicated_Server) installation) with the parameters for my server (which gamemode, which map, etc). `srcds_run` takes these parameters and sets some environment variables, and then runs the actual server binary (as well as has some logic to restart the server binary after a crash, update the server, etc.).

`srcds_run` has a lot of logic so I don't want to bypass it and run the binary directly (unless someone more experienced with srcds servers thinks that's a better option), I'd rather just have `systemctl` and `journalctl` show the logs of the server binary. I tried using `Type=forking` but then running `systemctl restart gmod` would hang, so I'm not sure if that's the right option here. Does anyone know how to get the proper logs in `systemctl`/a better way to run the server?

Comment: Perhaps add `StandardOutput=journal` under `[Service]`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, it resulted in the same logs as it did before. Is there a way to make systemd treat running a script the same as it would when running it normally as a user? Because if I run `run_gmod.sh` myself it starts the server console interactively and I can send commands to it, as well as see logs in real time (which is what I'd want in `journalctl`).

Comment: If you want to run a server that needs a console, typically people run `tmux` from the systemd Unit to start the server process. See this minecraft
[example](https://superuser.com/q/1366001/458747). You can then run `tmux` at any time to connect to the server and interact with it, or scroll back over its output.